# Session ID validation - Security - Ionic/Angular

Tags: angularjs, security, ionic-framework

I have been struggling for the past month on the solution to this.

When the user get's logged in, a session token is created in the DB and stored in the localStorage. This enables me to validate the user (by sneding the sessionID to the server and comparing its value to the value stored on the DB) every time a critical server call is made, but if I copy a particular session ID from the localStorage of any user I can paste on my localStorage and be validated too. This is a very big gap that I need to fill. What is the correct approach to validate the sessionID and avoid someone from copy and pasting it? How to I make the localStorage encoded to the user?

Notes: SessionID is created using JWT, 
       session token is completely random and created after logging in, 
       the value gets stored on a column of the user's column and saved on the    localStorage

Answer (score 3):

There is not anything you can do to completely protect against something like this.  If an attacker has physical access to a machine to be able to copy and paste from local storage, there is nothing you can do to stop them.

There are a few things you can do to slightly mitigate it, but they are more window dressing than anything else, and they usually cause more problems than they solve.  One of this is pinning the session to an IP address.  If the session begins at one address, and then moves to another address, you can invalidate the session and force the user to re-authenticate.  However, this causes many problems with legitimate users as their machine hops across networks.  Mobile devices have exacerbated this, but even stationary machines have trouble keeping a steady IP address.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your input. I agree that the ip address pinning sounds problematic.

Comment: +1 for a good, sensible answer. A couple of enhancements which *may* add some value is to change the token regularly (say every 10 minutes) to reduce the window of opportunity for copying the token (and log replay attempts) and also make sure to provide an explicit logout function which shreds the copy in local storage.

Comment: Also note that storing the session identifier in local storage makes it susceptible to XSS. Any single XSS in your application can be used to steal this from the client without physical access. This may or may not be acceptable in your scenario. A more secure solution is to store it in an httpOnly cookie, but then you have no access in Javascript (that's the point) and also have to care about things like CSRF.